# Copying worksheets using dynamic array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want copy worksheets in to new file. Every file should be saved per country - thing is I have different worksheets (clients) per country and the list might change in the future. So I created list like to this to be able easily edit the code in the future, this of course listed in Excel Worsheet:

```
Sales Org     Tabs

BE01          Albro

DK01          Stockmann", "Mister", "Ginsborg

IT01          La Rinascente", "Arcobaleno
```

In column "Tabs" I listed Sheets I want to be copied per file and Sales Organization represents file name.

My code works in case of BE01, however when it comes to DK01 I receive "Subscript out of range" error...

Can any one tell me what how to fix this?

```
    Sub SaveFile()
'
Dim Savefolder As String
Dim Filetype As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim Name As String
Dim Eufile As String
Dim TodayDate As String
Dim list As String


lastrow = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Savefolder = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("D2")
Filetype = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("E2")
Filename = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("F2")
 TodayDate = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")

    Dim array_db() As String
   ReDim array_db(lastrow - 2, 1)


    For row_number = 2 To lastrow

    array_db(row_number - 2, 0) = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("A" & row_number)
    array_db(row_number - 2, 1) = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("B" & row_number)
  Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(array_db)

            list = array_db(i, 1)
        Sheets(Array(list)).Copy
    Name = array_db(i, 0)
       Eufile = Savefolder & "\" & Filename & " " & TodayDate & " " & Name & Filetype



   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Eufile
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Where in the code is the error generated?

Comment: When code is during a second loop on line Sheets(Array(list)).Copy, so when it supposed to copy more than one worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern to select multiple sheets dynamically:

```
Dim sheetnames, i As Long

sheetnames = Split("Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3", "|")
Worksheets(sheetnames(0)).Select

For i = LBound(sheetnames) + 1 To UBound(sheetnames)
    Worksheets(sheetnames(i)).Select False
Next
```

In other words, change your column B to be the sheet names separated by a suitable character, for example the pipe character ("|") and then use the above. The Worksheet.Select method has an option paramater named "Replace", and setting this to false means the sheet will be selected in addition to the currently selected sheet.

Edit:

By the way, you don't have to read the cell values into an array one by one. You can do it all in one step using a variant array:

```
Dim array_db() as variant

array_db = Sheets("Macro Control").Range("A2").Resize(lastrow-1,2).Value
```

It is also advisable to specify which dimension's ubound to get: UBound(array_db,1). Your code works because it finds the first dimension's ubound by default, but that is not always the ubound you want.

Comment: Awesome! I used your code and selection is working as I needed, but how I can copy selected sheets to new workbook?

Comment: For what it's worth, you could have copied the selected sheets using ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for suggestion, SPLIT helped: this how I solved it:

```
sheetnames = Split(array_db(i, 1), "|")

    Sheets(sheetnames).Copy
```

Of course above I say where I take array_db from... Anyway, split made it possible to use text in single cell as a list of tabs to be copied... I also didn't declare "sheetnames"...

Below simplified code:

```
  Sub SaveFile()

Dim lastrow As Integer




lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim array_db()
   ReDim array_db(lastrow - 2, 1)


    For row_number = 2 To lastrow

    array_db(row_number - 2, 0) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)
    array_db(row_number - 2, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row_number)
  Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(array_db)

sheetnames = Split(array_db(i, 1), "|")

    Sheets(sheetnames).Copy





    Next


End Sub
```